# When is it ok to test private method?

Tags: testing, methods, private

I red several diverging opinion on testing private method. I was wondering as of today, what is the defacto convention with the testing of private method. Is it ok to Test them ?

If not, why is that, so many testing tool, enable to test them? I'm using scalatest, and there is something for that. I beleive this must be because in certain situation it is pretty useful. On the other hand i red, recommendation such as, test behavior not method.

Hence with this confusion i was wondering if anyone could share his experience and wisdom on the matter. When would it be appropriate to test them and when to avoid them? What are the general guidelines.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Test behavior not method" is a good approach. What it means for a unit test is that you are testing your class from a "user" perspective. And all your private methods should eventually be called from your public methods. Otherwise why they ever in your class in the first place?

In short - you should always test your private methods indirectly from your public methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Denis. However how would you justify the existence of special support in most framework to test private method? What is the point ?

Comment: Also I must admit that I found myself feeling weird when writing a private method, and having to break this cycle of TDD in a certain way. Meaning that, for the private method I would be testing things manually anyway, to be sure that it produce what I want, while applying real TDD for my public method. E.g. I would apply given when then in testing my public behavior, and manual testing for my private methods. I just find it odd. One get so much use to breaking down code and thoughts  using TDD technics but must roll back to old habit for private methods

Comment: Is it right? To me to not break the TDD cycle, then the best way is to break my test as well. More specifically, if my methods are really representing internal steps of my behavior then, my test should check the result of all those steps. For instance, with "Given When Then" + "And", the And Keyword, allows for conjunction of "result check" or "condition". Hence one could therefore, progress incrementally in testing the all behavior by checking the result of the different steps using "And". So in a sense you'd have "Then" testing the first private method, and the "And" the second and so on....